# Using NumPy arrays as indices to NumPy arrays

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

I have a 3x3x3 NumPy array:

```py
>>> x = np.arange(27).reshape((3, 3, 3))
>>> x
array([[[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8]],

       [[ 9, 10, 11],
        [12, 13, 14],
        [15, 16, 17]],

       [[18, 19, 20],
        [21, 22, 23],
        [24, 25, 26]]])
```

Now I create an ordinary list of indices:

```py
>>> i = [[0, 1, 2, 1], [2, 1, 0, 1], [1, 2, 0, 1]]
```

As expected, I get four values using this list as the index:

```py
>>> x[i]
array([ 7, 14, 18, 13])
```

But if I now convert `i` into a NumPy array, I won't get the same answer.

```py
>>> j = np.asarray(i)
>>> x[j]
array([[[[ 0,  1,  2],
         [ 3,  4,  5],
         [ 6,  7,  8]],

        [[ 9, 10, 11],
         [12, 13, 14],
         [15, 16, 17]],

        [[18, 19, 20],
         [21, 22, 23],
         [24, 25, 26]],

       ...,
       [[[ 9, 10, 11],
         [12, 13, 14],
         [15, 16, 17]],

        [[18, 19, 20],
         [21, 22, 23],
         [24, 25, 26]],

        [[ 0,  1,  2],
         [ 3,  4,  5],
         [ 6,  7,  8]],

        [[ 9, 10, 11],
         [12, 13, 14],
         [15, 16, 17]]]])
```

Why is this so?  Why can't I use NumPy arrays as indices to NumPy array?

Comment: [This](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#indexing-multi-dimensional-arrays) might be worth reading. The last example is most relevant to you.

Comment: Note that you can always convert NumPy arrays back to lists: `x[j.tolist()]` yields `[ 7 14 18 13]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x[j]` is the equivalent of `x[j,:,:]`

```
In [163]: j.shape
Out[163]: (3, 4)

In [164]: x[j].shape
Out[164]: (3, 4, 3, 3)
```

The resulting shape is the shape of `j` joined with the last 2 dimensions of `x`.  `j` just selects from the 1st dimension of `x`.

`x[i]` on the other hand, is the equivalent to `x[tuple(i)]`, that is:

```
In [168]: x[[0, 1, 2, 1], [2, 1, 0, 1], [1, 2, 0, 1]]
Out[168]: array([ 7, 14, 18, 13])
```

In fact `x(tuple(j)]` produces the same 4 item array.

The different ways of indexing numpy arrays can be confusing.

Another example of how the shape of the index array or lists affects the output:

```
In [170]: x[[[0, 1], [2, 1]], [[2, 1], [0, 1]], [[1, 2], [0, 1]]]
Out[170]: 
array([[ 7, 14],
       [18, 13]])
```

Same items, but in a 2d array.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [docs for numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html), what you are doing is "Integer Array Indexing", you need to pass each coordinate in as a separate array:

```
j = [np.array(x) for x in i]

x[j]
Out[191]: array([ 7, 14, 18, 13])
```